# Why doesn't this.$el.append() work?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to follow along http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals.  I'm not getting how $el is supposed to work in a view.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Dashboard</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>

    <ol class="foo" id="recent-station">
    </ol>

    <!-- Templates -->
    <script type="text/template" id="station-template">
      <li><%= station %></li>
    </script>

    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js"></script>

    <script src="static/js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And script.js is:

```
var RecentStation = Backbone.Model.extend( {
    defaults: {
        station: "",
    },

    initialize: function() {
        console.log('initialized: ' + JSON.stringify(this));

        this.on('change', function() {
            console.log('changed: ' + JSON.stringify(this));
        })
    }
});

var RecentStationView = Backbone.View.extend( {
    tagName: 'ol',
    id: 'recent-station',

    initialize: function() {
        this.model.bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this));
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log('render');
        this.$el.append('<li>foo</li>');
        $('ol#recent-station').append('<li>bar</li>');
        return this;
    },
});

var recent = new RecentStation();
var recentView = new RecentStationView({model: recent});
recent.set('station', 'My Station');
```

The interesting stuff is happening in the render function.  I can see "render" logged to the console, and the "bar" text gets appended to the  node, but not the "foo" text.  I thought this.$el and $('ol#recent-station') were the same thing, but obviously not.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify a dom element using `el` attribute, one will be created using `tagName`,`id`,`className`, and `attributes` from the view.

In your case you don't specify an `el` attribute in your view so you create an element that looks like:

```
<ol id='recent-station'></ol>
```

You then append `<li>foo</li>` into it, but your view element is still not in the `DOM`.

`$('ol#recent-station')` returns the dom element included in your `html` which is different than your view element, but has the same attributes.

So, in your example you would need to specify an existing element by supplying an `el` attribute.

```
 var RecentStationView = Backbone.View.extend( {
   // remove tagName and id
   el:'#recent-station',

   /* rest of your code below */
```

A fiddle with the changes, http://jsfiddle.net/DsRJH/.